# Postgresql preset disabled

Tags: database, postgresql, command, systemctl

i'm trying to start postgresql with systemctl, but the preset is disabled. I need postgresql to start armitage. How can I enable the preset?

[image: image showing command used and response]

i've tried another command to enable the service, but the preset is still disabled

Comment: please don'zt post inages of code and error messages see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"preset: disabled" only means that the service wasn't set to autostart right after the installation, and you activated that later ("enabled").

That has nothing to do with dependencies between services.

Comment: ok, but is there any possibilty to enable that preset? postgresql does not start, it finishes at the exact moment when it is started

Comment: That has nothing to do with whether autostart is enabled or not. Look at the log file. Try to start the database manually with `pg_ctl` and see what happens.